# Implementing a delay ($timeout) to a $http request with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, timeout, angular-resource

I have a particular function dependant on a (previously executed) service that will trigger multiple queries to a 3rd party API. This API with cancel the requests if it gets too many of them too quick. Is there a way to set a delay to the $http query?

Here is my $http code:

```
$scope.getImages = function (title, name) {
  $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json').
   success(function(data4) {
     $scope.images = data4;
   });
}
```

**EDIT** Upon request I paste my whole JS (probably I should have done so from the start)

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

  function Ctrl($scope, $http) {
    var search = function(name) {
      if (name) {
        $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5').
          success(function(data3) {
            $scope.clicked = false;
            $scope.results = data3.results;
          });
      }
      $scope.reset = function () {
        $scope.sliding = false;
        $scope.name = undefined;
      }
    }
    $scope.$watch('name', search, true);

    $scope.getDetails = function (id) {
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id).
        success(function(data) {
            $scope.artist = data;
        });
      $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/artists/' + id + '/releases?page=1&per_page=10').
        success(function(data2) {
            $scope.releases = data2.releases;
        });
      $scope.clicked = true;
      $scope.sliding = true;
    }


    $scope.getImages = function (title, name) {
        $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=e8aefa857fc74255570c1ee62b01cdba&artist=' + name + '&album='+ title +'&format=json').
          success(function(data4) {
              $scope.images = data4;
          });
      }


  };
```

Comment: Your $http code only shows a single call. Can you show how you're doing the multiple requests?

Comment: Sure, I'll update right away.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you will want to debounce your calls somehow, something simple like this should work. It will make the call every 300ms unless search(name) is called again before it fires.

```
var debounce = null;

var search = function(name) {
  $timeout.cancel(debounce);

  if (name) {
    debounce = $timeout(function() {
        $http.get('http://api.discogs.com/database/search?type=artist&q='+ name +'&page=1&per_page=5')
             .success(function(data3) {
                 $scope.clicked = false;
                 $scope.results = data3.results;
             });
    },300);
  }
  $scope.reset = function () {
    $scope.sliding = false;
    $scope.name = undefined;
  }
}
```